# numba argument argtypes deprecated keyword

Tags: python, numba

When i type following code :

```
mandel_numba = numba.jit(restype=uint32, argtypes=[float32, float32, uint32])(mandel)
```

and get error message

```
 raise DeprecationError(_msg_deprecated_signature_arg.format('argtypes'))
numba.errors.DeprecationError: Deprecated keyword argument `argtypes`. Signatures should be passed as the first positional argument.
```

My numba version is 0.28.0, i know that numba 0.18 version removes the old deprecated and undocumented argtypes and restype arguments to the @jit decorator.

please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is telling you what it expects

```
Signatures should be passed as the first positional argument.
```

So instead of

```
numba.jit(restype=uint32, argtypes=[float32, float32, uint32])
```

They should be positional

```
numba.jit(uint32(float32, float32, uint32))
```